# Why Java still keeps Iterator , when we can iterate a collection with enhanced for loop?

Tags: java

May be: Iterator has a remove() which allows to modify collection. Is there any other reason? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can never remove a public API, can we:)

Answer (score 4):

The enhanced for loop is just a syntactic sugar that enables you to iterate over an Iterable (or array) with less code.

`Iterator` and `Iterable` enable you to perform enhanced for loops on custom classes, and are used behind the scenes to implement the enhanced for loop for Collections and any other classes that implement `Iterable`.

Therefore, without the `Iterator` and `Iterable` interfaces, there is no enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fact that Eran mentioned, there are other uses for `Iterator`.

One example is to write a loop that stops when the next value meets some condition (or just when some condition is true, unrelated to the next item). You could do an `if` inside your `for` and break out of the loop, but an `Iterator` allows you to do something like

```
while ( iter.hasNext() && someCondition(...) ) {
    ...
};
```

which may be clearer than a `break` in an `if` in a `for`.

Moreover, there are collections that have additional iterators, not just the one used to read them forward. `TreeSet`, for example, has a `decendingIterator()`, which returns an `Iterator` that allows you to read it backwards.